# $block->getViewModel() returning NULL

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, overriding

I am overriding the layout and adding ViewModel in that layout but when I try to fetch the ViewModel getting below error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCodes() on null

My XML files look life which resides under

> /app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_Review/layout/override/base/review_product_list.xml

```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">+
   <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product_additional_data">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Custom\ProductModel\ViewModel\LocaleInfo</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
     </body>
</page>
```

and my ViewModel resides under

> Custom/ProductModel/ViewModel/LocaleInfo.php

and files look like

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver as LocaleResolver;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class LocaleInfo implements ArgumentInterface
{
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $localeResolver;

    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        LocaleResolver $localeResolver
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->localeResolver = $localeResolver;
    }

    public function getCodes($storeId = null)
    {
        $configPath = $this->localeResolver->getDefaultLocalePath();
        $localeCode = $this->scopeConfig->getValue($configPath, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId);

        return $localeCode;
    }
}
```

trying to fetch like below

```
$myViewModel = $block->getViewModel();
echo $myViewModel->getCodes();
```

Comment: Please provide the phtml file location and also do you have namespace declaration like `namespace Custom\ProductModel\ViewModel;` ? You also need to clear your caches and perform compilation

Comment: app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_Review/templates/product/view/list.phtml thats the phtml file location

Comment: Yes I have declared namespace as well

Comment: try with `$myViewModel = $block->getData('view_model');` instead of `$myViewModel = $block->getViewModel();`

Answer (score 0):

This is the block you are referencing in your layout handle XML file.

```
<block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView" 
       name="product.info.product_additional_data" 
       as="product_additional_data" 
       template="Magento_Review::product/view/list.phtml"
/>
```

You are referencing this block with its alias name; i.e, `product_additional_data` which is wrong. You should refer it with its name; i.e, `product.info.product_additional_data`.

So you should change your code like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">+
   <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.product_additional_data">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Custom\ProductModel\ViewModel\LocaleInfo</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
     </body>
</page>
```

After this changes made please clear your cache and then you are good to go.

### EDIT

Your layout update XML file location also seems wrong. It should be like:

> app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_Review/layout/review_product_list.xml

Comment: No luck :( still have same error nothing change

Comment: @Daniel_12 see my edit.

Comment: I am overriding layout and  I think its location is correct. check this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

Comment: But I tried as you say but still no luck same error

Comment: @Daniel_12 you here did a theme override. So the location should be as shown in my answer. You can see that in the given link too. With this, your code should work. I cannot see any other mistakes. check your logs for any errors.

Comment: @Daniel_12 which is your environment mode: production or development? did you clear the cache? recompilation is done?

Comment: nothing in log file but I dnt know why its not working

Comment: Make sure your Module `Custom_ProductModel` is working

Comment: yes in developer mode and my Module is also enabled and working

Answer (score 0):

instead of `view_model` please write `viewModel`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">+
   <body>
       <referenceBlock name="product_additional_data">
            <arguments>
                 <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Custom\ProductModel\ViewModel\LocaleInfo</argument>
             </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same situation and it worked once I used the view model argument name with underscore. Same as below as per the M2 Docs.

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">OrangeCompany\Catalog\ViewModel\MyNewViewModel</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html

Because on phtml file it was only possible to use `$block->getViewModel()` when we use `name="view_model"` otherwise we couldn't access this instance using `get()` instead of that we may have to use `getData('unique_name')`.

In your sample code, I notice that `<referenceBlock name="product_additional_data">` but I think it should be `<referenceBlock name="product.additional.data">` as per the M2 Docs and also it should be the same name where that you refer the block name.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing an issue where my view_model was working fine on product detail page for `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml`, but  `$block->getData('view_model')` was null on list page.
Then after digging a bit I added this code inside catalog_category_view.xml for frontend and it worked. Passed the viewModel class referencing `product.price.render.default` block.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.price.render.default">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\ViewModel\PriceInfo</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicly the process is

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
        <referenceBlock name="block.name">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="my_view_model" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\ViewModel\MyViewModel</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
     </body>
</page>
```

Your Class MyViewModel should implement `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface`

Then in the block you can get your view model by

```
$block->getData('my_view_model');
```

or

```
$block->getMyViewModel();
```

Be careful to not use too simplistic names like "view_model" cause you may override something that is needed in the page.

In the case that the above is not working, make sure there is no plugin that removes data from the block itself.